# Cluster Level Logging with Elasticsearch and Kibana does not work in kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, kibana, kubernetes

I am trying to setup cluster logging following below link

http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/logging-elasticsearch.html

my config-default.sh

```
# Optional: Enable node logging.
ENABLE_NODE_LOGGING=**true**

LOGGING_DESTINATION=${LOGGING_DESTINATION:-**elasticsearch**}

# Optional: When set to true, Elasticsearch and Kibana will be setup as part of the cluster bring up.
ENABLE_CLUSTER_LOGGING=true

ELASTICSEARCH_LOGGING_REPLICAS=${ELASTICSEARCH_LOGGING_REPLICAS:-1}
```

Command

```
$ sudo kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system

NAME                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

kube-dns-v9-epplg   4/4       Running   0          20h

kube-ui-v3-i4von    1/1       Running   0          18h
```

As you can see that I enabled logging and set logging destination = elasticsearch. I don't see elasticsearch-logging or fluentd-elasticsearch or kibana-logging when i do get pods. It seems like replication controller, service or pods is not created, do I need do anything else to bring up the ElasticSearch and Kibana?

Comment: Clearer formatting - the user didn't use code blocks

Answer (score 2):

Where are you starting your cluster? I tried to reproduce this on GCE using both the 1.0.7 release and from HEAD and wasn't able to.

Using the 1.0.7 release:

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-logging-v1-6x82b                 1/1       Running   0          3m
elasticsearch-logging-v1-s4bj5                 1/1       Running   0          3m
fluentd-elasticsearch-kubernetes-minion-ijpr   1/1       Running   0          1m
fluentd-elasticsearch-kubernetes-minion-nrya   1/1       Running   0          2m
fluentd-elasticsearch-kubernetes-minion-ppls   1/1       Running   0          1m
fluentd-elasticsearch-kubernetes-minion-sy4x   1/1       Running   0          2m
kibana-logging-v1-6qka9                        1/1       Running   0          3m
kube-dns-v8-9hyzm                              4/4       Running   0          3m
kube-ui-v1-11r3b                               1/1       Running   0          3m
monitoring-heapster-v6-4uzam                   1/1       Running   1          3m
monitoring-influx-grafana-v1-euc3a             2/2       Running   0          3m
```

From head:

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-logging-v1-9gqs8                 1/1       Running   0          3m
elasticsearch-logging-v1-edb97                 1/1       Running   0          3m
etcd-server-events-kubernetes-master           1/1       Running   0          3m
etcd-server-kubernetes-master                  1/1       Running   0          3m
fluentd-elasticsearch-kubernetes-master        1/1       Running   0          2m
fluentd-elasticsearch-kubernetes-minion-6id6   1/1       Running   0          1m
fluentd-elasticsearch-kubernetes-minion-n25a   1/1       Running   0          1m
fluentd-elasticsearch-kubernetes-minion-x4wa   1/1       Running   0          1m
heapster-v10-ek03n                             1/1       Running   0          3m
kibana-logging-v1-ybsad                        1/1       Running   0          3m
kube-apiserver-kubernetes-master               1/1       Running   0          3m
kube-controller-manager-kubernetes-master      1/1       Running   0          3m
kube-dns-v9-dkmad                              4/4       Running   0          3m
kube-scheduler-kubernetes-master               1/1       Running   0          3m
kube-ui-v3-mt7nw                               1/1       Running   0          3m
l7-lb-controller-b56yf                         2/2       Running   0          3m
monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v2-lxufh           2/2       Running   0          3m
```

The only thing I changed in `config-default.sh` is the KUBE_LOGGING_DESTINATION variable from gcp to elasticsearch:

```
$ git diff cluster/gce/config-default.sh
diff --git a/cluster/gce/config-default.sh b/cluster/gce/config-default.sh
index fd31820..2e37ebc 100755
--- a/cluster/gce/config-default.sh
+++ b/cluster/gce/config-default.sh
@@ -58,7 +58,7 @@ ENABLE_CLUSTER_MONITORING="${KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_MONITORING:-googleinfluxdb}"

 # Optional: Enable node logging.
 ENABLE_NODE_LOGGING="${KUBE_ENABLE_NODE_LOGGING:-true}"
-LOGGING_DESTINATION="${KUBE_LOGGING_DESTINATION:-gcp}" # options: elasticsearch, gcp
+LOGGING_DESTINATION="${KUBE_LOGGING_DESTINATION:-elasticsearch}" # options: elasticsearch, gcp

 # Optional: When set to true, Elasticsearch and Kibana will be setup as part of the cluster bring up.
 ENABLE_CLUSTER_LOGGING="${KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_LOGGING:-true}"
```

Comment: I am running kubernetes cluster on my local VM's(Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) and it looks like I am using v1.0.6 version.


$sudo kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6", GitCommit:"388061f00f0d9e4d641f9ed4971c775e1654579d", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6", GitCommit:"388061f00f0d9e4d641f9ed4971c775e1654579d", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Comment: Which instructions did you follow to setup kubernetes?

Comment: Which file did you modify? The instructions you linked to talked about modifying the `config-default.sh` file for creating a GCE cluster. The `config-default.sh` file for Ubuntu defaults to elastic search but node logging disabled (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh#L43-L44).

Comment: @EricTune ..I followed the  'Kubernetes Deployment On Bare-metal Ubuntu Nodes' http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu.html. Also I did KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./deployAddons.sh. Pleas note I have applications and cotainers up and running in two nodes and have no issues.

Comment: @RobertBailey.. I modifed  kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh and I did enable node logging, you can see that in my initialpost. ENABLE_NODE_LOGGING=true

Comment: It's possible that those fields don't work on ubuntu (and were just left in when that script was copied from another provider). Logging/monitoring and considered cluster addons, and the ubuntu script to deploy addons (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/cluster/ubuntu/deployAddons.sh) only seems to reference DNS. Even on the master branch, where support for kube-ui has been added to the addons script I don't see support for cluster logging or node logging.

Comment: @RobertBailey..yes its not clear just reading document but if you look at the link http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/logging-elasticsearch.html it says 'Here we describe how to set up a cluster to ingest logs into Elasticsearch and view them using Kibana as an alternative to Google Cloud Logging'  so I assumed this will work on ubuntu. Now I am trying to start the logging rc's and service's manually and see if that works. Thanks

Comment: Sorry that the documentation wasn't clearer :/. If you'd like to, we would appreciate a pull request to help the next person who runs into this.

Comment: I was able to start the elasticsearch and kibana manually running es-controller.yaml,es-service.yaml,kibana-controller.yaml,kibana-service.yaml under kubernetes/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch but ran into issues  configuring an index pattern in kibana. I am getting 'Pattern does not match any existing indices'..I might be missing something.

Comment: I am kind of new to open-source world and just started looking into 'how to contribute to open-source(kubernetes) but I am not sure if I am ready to do the pull request yet but would love to start as soon as possible. Any help on getting started on contribution(small) is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/development.md